# Ceiling fan question

Tags: capacitor, coil, fan

Does anyone know what this is? Usually ceiling fans only have a capacitor across the start winding but this one includes a coil. Why the added coil?[image]

Comment: Looks like it might be a common-mode choke, as part of a line filter?

Comment: Thanks Hearth, that makes sense.